# Am I altering an object or a copy of that object?

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I'm looking at some code and I want to make sure I understand whether some changes made to objects are actually made to those objects or copies of those objects.

Here's a sample:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
{
    DataObject myItem = (DataObject)myList.get(i);
    myItem.setString("someKey", "someValue"); 
}
```

myList is a List of DataObjects, so I'm not sure what the purpose was of casting the item to a DataObject after calling the get() method on the list. But I wonder how this is handled when it is compiled -- will the cast create a new object, and then the setString() method will be called on that new object and not affect the object in the list? Or is myItem referencing the actual item in the list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still a reference to the item in the list after casting. A copy is not created.

List returns a type of the Object class, so that it can be used for any type of `Object` (as all classes extend `Object`). In order to call setString though, you need to to cast the reference type to something more specific, so that the compiler knows what kind of object you are calling it on.

Using generics e.g. `List` with your list to specify the types will mean you don't have to cast, but may not be suitable if you can't control the List creation or don't know or want to restrict what types of Objects may be in it.

Answer (score 1):

The cast will not create a new object, it will just tell the compiler 'hey, I know what I am doing, and this is a `DataObject`'.

Without knowing the type of the actual `List` implementation, we cannot say whether or not what you are getting is the same object.  If you are using one of the Java Collections collections (ArrayList, LinkedList, etc...), then it would be the same object instance.  But I could imagine an implementation (made by myself of course!) that could return copies rather than the underlying instance.

```
public class MyList<T> implements List<T> {
    private List<T> backingList = new ArrayList<T>();

    //methods to fulfil List interface contract...

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        T t = backingList.get(index);
        return makeCopy(t);
    }

    private T makeCopy(T t) {
        //make a copy of t!
    }
}
```

And it is because of that, that we cannot tell (without you telling us the underlying type) if the `get(int)` method will return a copy or not.

Comment: +1 very good point about not knowing what the list will internally do. That's another reason for using immutable list elements.

Comment: Oh yeah, we are all assuming this is a well-behaved List implementation.  But the get() method *could* be returning a copy.  But it is very unlikely.  However the cast itself will not create a new object.  Good call.

Comment: Good point! I should have mentioned, `myList` was declared earlier on in the code by calling the `getList()` method on an object of type `DataObject`.

Answer (score 1):

It is referencing the actual item in the list, all the cast does is tell the compiler to ignore the *declared* type, you know what the object's *actual* type is going to be. (But if you're wrong, you'll get a `ClassCastException` runtime, which is why casting should be avoided if possible. Without going into details, generics can for example help with that.)

Now, this kind of thing (modifying elements of a collection) works with lists without a problem but with `Set`s and for keys of `Map`s you must use immutable objects (basically objects whose fields can't change after the constructor is called), otherwise you can make a right mess. You should also avoid this if your collection is shared between multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you use generics, you don't need to cast, otherwise you need to cast because there is no way to know what type of objects list has.

***But I wonder how this is handled when it is compiled -- will the cast create a new object***

Compiler not going to create any objects. It just checks for syntax and semantics. While compiling that particular line, compiler knows reference is type DataObject, but list.get() returns object type which results in incompatible types. So, you need to explicitly cast.

Answer (score 0):

The cast will not create a new DataObject.  Casts will not generally create new objects, **except** when converting primitives to wrapper types, or an explicit or implied cast to String resulting in a call to the `toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

myList.get() may be defined to return a more generic type, such as Object for example. You cannot make a reference variable refer to a type more generic than itself. Therefore, you have to do the cast-

```
DataObject myItem = (DataObject) myList.get(i);
```

The cast will not create a new object. The cast will only make the variable myItem refer to the already existing object in the list. The setString() method, therefore, changes your actual object. Therefore, the object in the list is also changed, because it is the same object.

Answer (score 0):

If `myList` is declared as a typed list, like so:

```
List<DataObject> myList = new ArrayList<DataObject>();
```

Then a cast is not necessary. However, if it is an untyped `List`, then its `get` method will return an object of type `Object`. That could be why the cast is necessary (without seeing the declaration, I can't tell).

Having said that, the cast is not creating a new object, so what you've got is a new reference to the object that already exists in the list. This means that any modifications happen within `myList`.

Comment: The variable `myList` is declared by calling the `getList()` method on a `DataObject` earlier in the code. I probably should have mentioned that. But that makes sense then, they must have written it that way because the `get()` method was returning objects of type `Object`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the same Object.

The only thing that creates a `new` Object is -guess what? the `new` keyword. Some people my claim that `clone()` creates a new Object (if correctly implemented) but -guess what? in the clone function there is a `new` keyword somewhere!

Now, I do not know what kind of `myList` you're dealing with, but assuming that it's part of the Standard Java Libraries (`ArrayList, LinkedList, etc`) then you get the same Object.

P.S. Remember that Arrays are Objects too!